# Limitation on ChangeLink Method?

Tags: vba, excel

I came up with a bit of code to update links automatically for certain needs I had.
The hierarchy of my folders is :
-Parent folder  with parent file
 -SubFolder 1 with file 1
 -SubFolder 2 with file 2.1 file 2.2...

The main macro is called by the parent file and opens all files 2.x which are linked to the parent file and file 1. My code is

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

oldlinks = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)

For i = 1 To UBound(oldlinks)
    Filename = Right(oldlinks(i), Len(oldlinks(i)) - InStrRev(oldlinks(i), "\"))

    If Filename = "file1" Then
        newlink = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1) & "\SubFolder1\" & Filename
    ElseIf Filename = "ParentFile" Then
        newlink = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1) & "\" & Filename
    End If

    If newlink <> oldlinks(i) Then
        ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=oldlinks(i), NewName:=newlink, Type:=xlExcelLinks
    End If
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This seemed to work at first and today I stumbled with an Error 1004 on line

```
ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=oldlinks(i), NewName:=newlink, Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

It seems to me that it might not work because the root of the parent file is longer than before, and I tested it : it still works if the lenght of the path string (which I get with Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1)) is shorter.

I couldn't find any mention of such a limitation in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836537.aspx). Has anyone encountered it before ?

Thanks in advance